# Search function not working for multiple words

Tags: php, mysql, search, post, get

I have been using this search function on a website and it take words from posted words and searches the database. Iv adapted it so that it can accept things from another part of the website sent to it via GET. The problem I am having is when you send it multiple words such as searchstock=some search words it wont work. If I send it just single words such as searchstock=word using GET it works just fine, its only when multiple words are sent it doesnt work and just brings up all results in the database. The strange thing is multiple word searches work fine by POST.

```
    // Begin Search Section >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    function search($db) {
        if (isset($_POST['searchstock'])){$words = $_POST['searchstock'];}
        if (isset($_GET['searchstock'])){$words = $_GET['searchstock'];}

    $searchQuery = ''; // search query is empty by default
    $searchCondition = "(cultivar LIKE '%%' OR description LIKE '%%' OR species LIKE '%%' OR colour LIKE '%%')";
    $searchFieldName = 'cultivar'; // name of the field to be searched
    $searchFieldName2 = 'description';
    $searchFieldName3 = 'species';
    $searchFieldName4 = 'colour';
    if(isset($_POST['searchstock']))
    { // check if a query was submitted
    $searchQuery = trim($_POST['searchstock']); // getting rid of unnecessary white space
    $searchTerms = explode(" ", $searchQuery); // Split the words
    $searchCondition = "($searchFieldName LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')"; // Forming the condition for the sql
    $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName2 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName2 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
    $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName3 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName3 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
    $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName4 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName4 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['searchstock']))
    { // check if a query was submitted
    $searchQuery = trim($_GET['searchstock']); // getting rid of unnecessary white space
    $searchTerms = explode(" ", $searchQuery); // Split the words
    $searchCondition = "($searchFieldName LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')"; // Forming the condition for the sql
    $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName2 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName2 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
    $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName3 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName3 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
    $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName4 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName4 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
    }
    // the rest is just database connection and retrieving the results
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT * FROM stock WHERE $searchCondition;
    SQL;
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){        //Show your results here eg: $row['field1']
    $searchid = $row['id']; 
    $searchgenusid = $row['genusid'];
    // End Search
            // Search DB Function Start //
    $sql4 = <<<SQL
    SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `id` = '$searchid';
    SQL;
    if(!$stockresult = $db->query($sql4)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
    while($stockrow = $stockresult->fetch_assoc()){
```

Comment: Not sure but in get method only ascii characters allowed..Maybe this is the reason

Comment: And as i remember space is not an ascii character..

Answer (score 0):

```
function search($db) {
    $words=''
    if (isset($_POST['searchstock'])){$words = $_POST['searchstock'];}
    if (isset($_GET['searchstock'])){$words = $_GET['searchstock'];}
    if (!empty($words){
      $searchQuery = ''; // search query is empty by default
      $searchCondition = "(cultivar LIKE '%%' OR description LIKE '%%' OR species LIKE '%%' OR colour LIKE '%%')";
      $searchFieldName = 'cultivar'; // name of the field to be searched
      $searchFieldName2 = 'description';
      $searchFieldName3 = 'species';
      $searchFieldName4 = 'colour';
      $searchQuery = trim(words); // getting rid of unnecessary white space
      $searchTerms = explode(" ", $searchQuery); // Split the words
      $searchCondition = "($searchFieldName LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')"; // Forming the condition for the sql
      $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName2 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName2 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
      $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName3 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName3 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
      $searchCondition .= " OR ($searchFieldName4 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR $searchFieldName4 LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%')";
      // the rest is just database connection and retrieving the results
      $sql = <<<SQL
      SELECT * FROM stock WHERE $searchCondition;
      SQL;
      if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ 
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
      }
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $searchid = $row['id']; 
        $searchgenusid = $row['genusid'];

        //if its work on _POST then should also work on _GET
        //do what ever you want
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting errors when I copy and paste that, I can see after words the line isnt closed with a ; , if empty needs to be closed with ) but not sure where else it is causing it.

Comment: i didn't check i just make simple to understand you better but if you want use multiple columns with single word use SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCATENATE_WS(',', col1, col2, col3) LIKE %keyword%.